# Oracle Database 11G Installation "Error al llamar al destino 'install' del archivo make"

Tags: oracle-11g, installation

I get this error installing Oracle Database 11g in Linux..

```
INFO: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5: referencia a `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14' sin definir

INFO: collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1

INFO: make: *** [ctxhx] Error 1

INFO: Salida final del proceso iniciado.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Excepción devuelta de la acción: make
Nombre de la Excepción: MakefileException
Cadena de la Excepción: Error al llamar al destino 'install' del archivo make '/o/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk'. Consulte '/o/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2018-02-06_08-13-05AM.log' para obtener más información.
Gravedad de la Excepción: 1
```

Comment: Please have a look at log file: `/o/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2018-02-06_08-13-05AM.log` and try to paste additional information about this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

Try to link with g++ instead of gcc.

```
cd /bin
mv gcc gcc.save
ln -s g++ gcc
```

and run the installer again. as suggested on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774848/oracle-database-installation-issue-in-ins-ctx-mk